# Proxy Authentication Error while calling FedEx webservice

Tags: c#, web-services, proxy, fedex

I am trying to call the FedEx tracking webservice. Currently I am running the sample application provided by FedEx itself (Added my test account number and other details). When I run the application, I get the following error:

The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required.

I am inside a proxy at my organization and I tried provided the proxy server details to the webservice client using the WebProxy class as:

```
trackService.Proxy = WebProxy.GetDefaultProxy();
```

and also by providing the proxy server details as:

```
trackService.Proxy = new WebProxy("IP",8080);
```

But I still keep getting the same error!! Could somebody help me how to resolve this problem?

Thanks in advance,
Regards,
Abdel Olakara

Comment: Are you assigning `trackService.Proxy` twice?

Comment: no.. i tried both these methods of setting the proxy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you seem to be missing is the proxy *credentials*. Try this:

```
trackService.Proxy = new WebProxy("IP", 8080);
trackService.Proxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(
    username, password, domain);
```

Comment: Thanks.. once I provided the credentials.. I got the webservice working :)